# looking for classification algorithm that maximize good results

Tags: classification, binary-data, supervised-learning

We are looking for statistic / machine learning algorithm that will yield the “best” results for the following supervised classification scenario

We have a sample of around 300 rows, each row with 55 parameters and a result that can be either 1 or -1 - binary classification 
We want to maximize the number good results minus number bad results and we don't need to classify all the samples. For example, an algorithm that classify correctly 20 good results and 0 bad results is better than algorithm that classify 100 good results and 90 bad results

Already try various machine learning algorithm without success, probably due to the fact that there are only 300 rows in the sample. Logistic regression yield good results in training but bad results for the testing

here is a sample file 
https://gist.github.com/shasho/8354d8fc22ad78b163f64f4ff32718ef

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide similar simulated data?

Comment: added a sample file

Comment: "Good" and "bad" results makes it sound as if you have not considered the utility/loss/cost function nor justified why this problem should be cast as a classification problem and not a probability estimation problem.

Comment: and if it a probability estimation problem, what is the way to get the optimal solution ?